# PHP, MySQL Registrar Form

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors','1');
    session_start();
    ?>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['signupbtn'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $retypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if ($firstname) {

    }
    else
    $echoFirstName = "You must enter your first name";

    if ($lastname) {

    }
    else
      $echoLastName = "You must enter your last name";

      if ($email) {
        if ( (strlen($email) >= 7 && (strstr($email, "@")) && (strstr($email, ".")))){
          require("../php/connect.php");
          if ($numrows == 0){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
              $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
              mysql_close();

          }
          else
            $echoEmailExists = "This email already exists";

        }
        else
          $echoInvalidEmail = "You must enter a valid email address";
      }
      else
        $echoEmail = "You must enter your email address";

        if ($country) {

        }
        else
          $echoCountry = "You must select your country";

          if ($state) {

          }
          else
            $echoState = "You must enter your state";

            if ($city) {

            }
            else
              $echoCity = "You must enter your city";

              if ($address) {
                require("../php/connect.php");
                if ($numrows == 0){
                  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE address='$address'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    mysql_close();
                }
                else
                  $echoAddressExists = "This address already exists";

              }
              else
                $echoAddress = "You must enter your address";

                if ($gender) {

                }
                else
                  $echoGender = "You must select your gender";

                  if ($zip) {

                  }
                  else
                    $echoZip = "You must enter your zip code";

                    if ($phone) {
                      require("../php/connect.php");
                      if ($numrows == 0){
                          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone='$phone'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            mysql_close();
                      }
                      else
                        $echoPhoneExists = "This phone number already exists";
                    }
                    else
                      $echoPhone = "You must enter your phone number";

                      if ($pass) {
                        if ($retypepass) {
                          if ( $pass === $retypepass ){
                            require("../php/connect.php");

                                    $cryptpass = crypt($pass);
                                      include_once ("../php/randStrGen.php");
                                      $pass_hash =                     randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
                                      $date = date("F d, Y");
                                      $code = md5(rand());

                                      mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                          '', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$country', '$state', '$city', '$address', '$gender', '$zip', '$phone', '$pass_hash', '0', '$date', '$code'
                                      )");

                                    if ($numrows == 1){

                                      $site = "http://stripemovies.tk";
                                      $webmaster = "noreply <noreply@dghosting.net>";
                                      $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                                      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
                                      $subject = "Activate Your Stripe Movies Account";
                                      $message = "Tak fordi at du har registreret dig. Klik på linket nedenunder for at aktivere din konto.\n";
                                      $message .= "$site/activation/?fn=" . $firstname . "&ln=" . $lastname . "&p=" . $pass_hash . "&e=" . $email . "";

                                      if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
                                      $echoRegistered = "<div class='form-side-info'><p><font color='red'>* </font>Du er blevet registreret. Du skal aktivere din konto fra aktiveringslinket sendt til <b>$email</b>.<br />Lad det tage 5 minutter at nå frem, ellers tjek din spam mappe</p></div>";
                                      $email = "";

                                      }
                                      else
                                        $echoFailEmail = "<font color='red'>* <span>Your activation link was not sent</span></font>";

                                    }
                                    else
                                      $echoFailRegister = "<font color='red'>* <span>Your account has not been created</span></font>";
                                    mysql_close();

                          }
                          else
                            $echoInvalidPass = "Your passwords does not match";

                        }
                        else
                          $echoRetypePass = "You must confirm your password";

                      }
                      else
                        $echoPass = "You must enter your password";




    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Stripe Movies - Sign Up</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
        <link href="http://stripemovies.tk/assets/theme_venera.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel:400|Oswald:300,400,700" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="mcZQqRYWJr6dSGKE58lcmAA7hTBr7jwlE5wmc5oz3kY=" name="csrf-token" />
    <link href="http://stripemovies.tk/fonts/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>
    <body>


<!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
    <![endif]-->
        <?php require("../header.php"); ?>



        <section class='section-wrapper create-account-page-w'>
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='span9'>
    <div class='white-card extra-padding'>
    <form action="http://stripemovies.tk/signup/index-2.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class='span12'>

    <h1 class='form-header'>Create Account</h1>

</div>
</div>
<div class='row-fluid'>
<div class='span12'>
<?php echo $echoRegistered; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>First Name <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoFirstName; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your first name...' type='text' name='first_name' value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
</div>
</div>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Last Name <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoLastName; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your last name...' type='text' name='last_name' value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Email Address <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoEmail; ?><?php echo $echoInvalidEmail ?><?php echo $echoEmailExists; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your email address...' type='text' name='email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
</div>
</div>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Country  <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoCountry; ?></span></font></label>
<?php include("countries.php"); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>State <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoState; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your state...' type='text' name='state' value="<?php echo $state; ?>">
</div>
</div>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>City <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoCity; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your city...' type='text' name='city' value="<?php echo $city; ?>">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Address <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoAddress; ?><?php echo $echoAddressExists; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your address...' type='text' name='address' value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
</div>
</div>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Gender <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoGender; ?></span></font></label>
<select name='gender'>
<option value="<?php if ($gender){ echo $gender;} else echo $gender; ?>"><?php if ($gender){ echo $gender;} else echo "Select your gender"; ?></option>
<option value='m'>Male</option>
<option value='f'>Female</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Zip Code <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoZip; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your zip code...' type='text' name='zip' value="<?php echo $zip; ?>">
</div>
</div>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Phone Number <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoPhone; ?><?php echo $echoPhoneExists; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your phone number with country code...' type='text' name='phone' value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Password <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoPass; ?><?php echo $echoInvalidPass; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Your password...' type='password' name='pass' value="<?php if($pass === $retypepass){ echo $pass;} elseif ($pass){ echo $pass;} ?>">
</div>
</div>
<div class='span4'>
<div class='control-group'>
<label>Confirm Password <font color="red">* <span><?php echo $echoRetypePass; ?><?php echo $echoInvalidPass; ?></span></font></label>
<input class='span4' placeholder='Password confirmation...' type='password' name='retypepass' value="<?php if($pass === $retypepass){ echo $retypepass;} ?>">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row-fluid'>
<div class='span12'>
<div class='form-actions no-margin-bottom'>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" name="signupbtn" type="submit">Complete Registration</button><?php echo $echoFailRegister; ?><?php echo $echoFailEmail; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class='span3'>
<div class='blog-side-text-block widget-filled widget-yellow'>
<h3>Some Tips:</h3>
<ul class='big-iconed-tips'>
<li>
<i class='icon-credit-card'></i>
Registration is free
</li>
<li>
<i class='icon-lock'></i>
100% Secured
</li>
<li>
<i class='icon-comments'></i>
24 Hours online support
</li>
<li>
<i class='icon-cogs'></i>
Customizable
</li>
<li>
<i class='icon-github'></i>
Host it on github
</li>
</ul>
<p>Ut diam arcu, dictum ut vulputate sed, iaculis nec lorem. Fusce pharetra nisl vitae nisl ultricies ut malesuada leo fringilla.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<?php require("../footer.php"); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that, when I register (even if the fields aren't filled out correctly) I can still register, and the same if the email is the same as the one in the mysql database.
And if the details are correct, it echo out that the account has not been created, even when it was.

Comment: what do you think this `if ($firstname) ` checks for in $firstname?

Comment: @Dagon If the field is filled out with characters, if not it will echo out "You must enter your first name"